# Problema al abrir varios libros excel con macros

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo libros con macros creadas en vba y si se abre un solo libro funciona perfectamente, pero al abrir otro libro con macros a la vez, ambos dejan de trabajar o trabajan erraticamente. No importa en que ordenador abra los libros, siempre tengo el mismo resultado.
Alguien me puede ayudar para solventar este problema?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estas macros se ejecutan al abrir el libro? o se ejecutan manualmente? cuando se crea una macro, muchas veces no se indica el workbook correctamente y se ejecuta el active workbook, lo que generará conflicto a la que abras más de un excel a la vez

Comment: Gracias Guillen,  Sí, se ejecutan al abrir el libro para presentar un formulario y después se van ejecutando macros conforme se va rellenando la hoja. He tratado de nombrar el libro pero tampoco funciona. Tanto es así que al cerrar los libros y dejando uno abierto tampoco recupera la funcionalidad.

Comment: entonces, sería conveniente que publicaras más detalladamente las macros de cada excel, y revisar si estás haciendo referencia al libro en particular dentro de cada macro

Comment: Guillen esta es la forma que lo nombro.Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim nomLibro As Workbook

nomLibro = Workbook.Name

' Verifica los usuarios, sino valido borra todo

   If Application.UserName = "luis sevilla" Then
        muestra
               
    Else

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
  'On Error Resume Next
        nomLibro.Sheets.add  // igual no es la correcta

Comment: nomLibro = Workbook.Name? Prueba a ponerle el nombre del fichero manualmente a ver si así te funcionan, y si no, sería probar con ActiveWorkbook.Name, ya que cuando abres un excel, éste se convierte en el active workbook, y luego trabajar con esa variable, por si cambias el focus activo del workbook

Comment: Muchas gracias Guillen. Así lo haré a ver qué resultado da.     Un saludo

Comment: @Guillen buenas tardes. Realicé los cambios y ha ido perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu consejo.

Comment: me alegro que te haya funcionado!